# @media print not working on google

Tags: printing, cross-browser, media, css, css-paged-media

I am trying to find out why `@media print` is not working on Chrome. It's fine with IE and FF.

I am working on print page for a coupon, but Chrome is printing a blank page.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Can you give us some example code?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a separeted css?

Try embedding the css inside the page to see if the problem persist.

The example bellow seems to work in the same page:

```
<style type="text/css">
    @media print{
    .button {display : none} 
    }
 </style>
```